# How to make SQL Server Object Explorer add a server using 2012 not 2014 in VS 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

When I click add SQL Server, in SQL Server Object Explorer panel in Visual Studio 2012, a connect to server window opens for Microsoft SQL Server 2014, however I have SQL Server 2012. How to make it add a server using SQL Server 2012?

Comment: When the "connect to server" window opens, just type in the server+instance name for your SQL Server 2012 instance - doesn't that work?

Comment: It does, but is this the way it should be? Should it say 2014 when I don't have SQL Server 2014?

Comment: What is the output when you run `SELECT @@VERSION` - the 2014 version number probably only refers to the "client" tools - the GUI - not the underlying database engine.....

Comment: Right @marc_s it only seems to be the "client" tool because once it goes in I have all the functionality, the version is 11.0.6020.0. Also even when I install the latest database tools for VS 2012 I see it download 2014 tools, so perhaps that's all it is.